# Entity SQL - Strangeness

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I'm getting data out of my object context using .CreateQuery(sqlStatement, parameterValues).  Please note that this the Entity SQL that I am using as a string constant being passed into the CreateQuery method, not a compiled LINQ query in my source code.

This works perfectly.  However there are some duplicate records...

```
ctx.CreateQuery<DbDataRecord>(@"SELECT  record.home_city, record.home_stabb 
FROM Employees AS record  
ORDER BY record.home_city SKIP 0 LIMIT 15",prms);
```

So I thought this would remove the duplicates:

```
ctx.CreateQuery<DbDataRecord>(@"SELECT DISTINCT record.home_city, record.home_stabb 
FROM Employees AS record  
ORDER BY record.home_city SKIP 0 LIMIT 15",prms);
```

Exact same statement, exact same object context.  However, when I add in the DISTINCT Modifier, I get the exception below.  I know all of the columns are correct because the first statement works perfectly. Jusjing by the exception, it appears to have a problem with the ORDER BY clause.

Is there something that I'm missing?  This makes no sense to me.

```
System.Data.EntitySqlException was unhandled by user code
Message='record.home_city' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near member access expression, line 1, column 95.
Source=System.Data.Entity
Column=95
ErrorContext=member access expression, line 1, column 95
```

Comment: I'll leave it to someone else to offer reasons why this might be going on, as I am not sure.  But as a possible work-around, have you tried doing `SELECT record.home_city, record.home_stabb FROM Employees AS record GROUP BY record.home_city, record.home_stabb ORDER BY record.home_city SKIP 0 LIMIT 15` ... just in case there is some translation/parsing error specific to DISTINCT

Comment: I'll try that. Unfortunately, though, the code I provided is from a proof of concept and in reality, 9 columns are used. so it would be a little quirky to constantly have to re-express them.  A good Idea, though.  SQL pretty much created identical execution plans for both approaches.

Comment: I agree, it would be klunky, and I really hope someone has an answer for you regarding why your specific example does not work.  Sometimes a klunky work-around is the best you can get but hopefully this is not one of those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below and then run a distinct later? 
I know distinct is main reason you are facing this problem, but at least you know another way to go around it.

```
ctx.CreateQuery<DbDataRecord>(@"SELECT VALUE record FROM Employees AS record  
ORDER BY record.home_city SKIP 0 LIMIT 15",prms);
```